# Generating All List (permuting)

Tags: c

I'm quite unsure why my code does this when I type 6 or more numbers/characters that it only display some of the output. (I know that numbers/characters does not affect anything).

For example if I type cat it'll list all the possible variations:
cat
cta
act
atc
tac
tca

But when I type in 123456 (or any 6+ lettered strings):
It start displaying at 462513-612345 (if you know what I mean). What happened to the rest (123456-462513)?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void swap (char *X, char *Y)
    {
      char Z;
      Z = *X;
      *X = *Y;
      *Y = Z;
    }

    void mixmatch (char *A, int i, int n)
    {
      int j;
      if (i == n)
         printf("%s\n", A);
      else
      {
         for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
         {
            swap((A+i), (A+j));
            mixmatch(A, i+1, n);
            swap((A+i), (A+j));
         }
      }
    }

    int main()
    {
       char A[100];
       printf ("Enter the string/set of numbers: ");
       gets(A);

       int k;
       k=strlen(A);
       mixmatch(A, 0, k-1);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of *A, i and n every time `mixmatch` is called? Maybe that will give you the clue...

Comment: I see nothing wrong, it works on my system - prints all permutations of 123456

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your code, the problem is the windows `cmd.exe` does not have enough buffer to show you *all* the permutations.

I tried with cygwin and it works flawlessly.

Here are the screenshots to prove it:

## with cmd.exe

[image]

## with cygwin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aniket is right.

Here's what to do:

You can increase cmd.exe's storage using the top-left menu's settings. Set buffer height to 9999.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I thought there was something wrong with my code!

Comment: Umm when I went to my settings, there's no such thing as buffer height. Under the Window tab, there are subtabs of Appearance, Behavior, Translation, Selection,and Colours. Ive looked thru all of them and no visible aspect of buffer height. What to do?

Comment: I only have WinXP. Here the tab is called "Layout". If this doesn't exist in your Windows then you could try cygwin.